# Failed to create agent because it is not close enough to the NavMesh Issue on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning to use Unity and creating enemy AI's. I keep getting this error that the agent is not close enough to the NavMesh but even if the agent is LITERALLY touching the NavMesh Surface I created, I'm still getting this error.

I have a NavMesh Agent component attached to the enemy object. And I created an empty gameobject and set it on the ground while attaching a NavMesh Surface component to it and baking.

I've extensively researched this issue but none of the fixes I found online were useful so this is my last resort basically lol. Hoping someone can figure out the issue here. Thanks!

Here's the code for the enemy AI:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    //player 2 AI
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    //player1
    public Transform player;

    public Transform Arms;

    public Transform stealBallPosition;

    public Transform Dribbling2;

    public Transform Basketball;

    public float sightRange, attackRange;
    public bool playerInSightRange, playerInAttackRange;

    public LayerMask whatIsGround, whatIsPlayer;

    public int score, stealCount;

    public void Start()
    {
        score = 5;
        stealCount = 0;
        player = GameObject.Find("Player1").transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }




    private void Update()
    {
        playerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, whatIsPlayer);
        playerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attackRange, whatIsPlayer);

        if (playerInSightRange && playerInAttackRange) stealBall();
        if (playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) chasePlayer();

    }

    private void stealBall()
    {
        Arms.position = stealBallPosition.position;
        Basketball.position = Dribbling2.position + Vector3.up * Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 5));
        score--;
        stealCount++;
    }

    private void chasePlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(player.position);
        transform.LookAt(player);
    }

}
```

[An Image of my Unity setup for the enemyAI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qamnP.jpg)

[An Image of my Unity setup for the NavMesh empty object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dybFL.jpg)

Comment: try sampling the position, getting nearest navmesh position and moving the character there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows, that the agent is actually not close enough to the surface (the actual blue area)

[image]

Toggle between "center" and "pivot" (I think it's Z-key, but scene window has a dropdown at the top). You will notice, that the contents of the "EnemyAI" prefab are not at (0,0,0). With prefabs, it can be tricky, so try unpacking the prefab, moving stuff to center, then create a new prefab from that.

When you did that, move the whole "EnemyAI" prefab to the navmesh surface, so that the green cylinder-shape (the "collider" of the agent) is very close to the ground.

Comment: good to hear. Might mark as accepted answer :)